# count self relation on Prisma error: table name specified more than once

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I am trying to count a self relation (followers) in Prisma2 (using PostgreSQL)

Model:

```
model User {
  id        String  @id @default(cuid())
  following User[]  @relation(name: "UserFollows")
  followers User[]  @relation(name: "UserFollows")
}
```

Query:

```
const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
  where: { id: userId },
  include: {
    _count: {
      select: { followers: true, following: true },
    },
  },
});
```

(using `previewFeatures = ["selectRelationCount"]`) and getting the following error:

> Invalid `prisma.user.findUnique()` invocation:
>
> Error occurred during query execution: ConnectorError(ConnectorError
> { user_facing_error: None, kind: QueryError(Error { kind: Db, cause:
> Some(DbError { severity: "ERROR", parsed_severity: Some(Error), code:
> SqlState("42712"), message: "table name "User" specified more than
> once", detail: None, hint: None, position: None, where_: None, schema:
> None, table: None, column: None, datatype: None, constraint: None,
> file: Some("parse_relation.c"), line: Some(423), routine:
> Some("checkNameSpaceConflicts") }) }) })

Does anybody have any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with self-relations and we hope to fix it soon. If you want to track this bug, follow this [github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/7893). Please feel free to add a comment to explain your use case/problem over there.

In the meantime, here are some workarounds that you can use:

#### Find count using nested read

You can use a [nested read](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/relation-queries) to return all the records in `followers` and `following` and find the length of those arrays to get the count. This seems like the most straightforward way, so long as you're okay with fetching all the followers/following records.

```js
 const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
            id: userId,
        },
        include: {
            followers: true,
            following: true,
        },
    });
    let followerCount = user.followers.length; 
    let followingCount = user.following.length;
```

#### Find count using separate count queries.

Alternatively, you can use the `count` API to find `followers` and `following` counts for a certain user.

```js
// number of followers for some user "x" = number of times x.id appaers in "following" relation of other users.
    const followerCount = await prisma.user.count({
        where: {
            following: {
                some: {
                    id: userId,
                },
            },
        },
    });

// number of users that user "x" is following = number of times x.id appaers in "followers" relation of other users.
    const followingCount = await prisma.user.count({
        where: {
            followers: {
                some: {
                    id: userId,
                },
            },
        },
    });
```

#### Change schema to use explicit many-to-many notation

If you're okay with slightly tweaking your schema, you can explicitly define the many-to-many relation table.

```
model Follows {
  follower    User @relation("follower", fields: [followerId], references: [id])
  followerId  String
  following   User @relation("following", fields: [followingId], references: [id])
  followingId String

  @@id([followerId, followingId])
}

model User {
  id        String  @id @default(cuid())
  followers Follows[] @relation("follower")
  following Follows[] @relation("following")
}
```

You should be able to run the count query without issues in this way.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late but for whoever may get stuck later yo can do something like this

```
const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ 
    where: { id: userId },
    include: {
        _count: true,
    },
});
```

this should output something like this

```
//user data
"_count": {
    "followers": 99,
    "following": 99
 }
```

you can then add them in your frontend

Comment: Will this count any relation? For example if I have another relation and I don't need to count it, will your solution include this as well?

Comment: yes if you only want followers for example you can do something like this
_count: { select: { followers: true } }
instead of _count: true